# How to import/export VPN settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, export, import

I have a VPN connection configured on my Windows 7 PC, and I'd like to export these settings to another computer.

I could simply tell the other user which settings to use, but I don't want to share my password. Ideally, I would just go on the other computer, set everything up, check the "Remember password" box and voilà.

This way, the other user would be able to use the VPN connection, without knowing the password. Unfortunately, the other user is pretty far (another country), so doing things in person is not an option.

Is there a way I could do this ?

I'm using Windows 7 built-in VPN client, but am open to using any (free) alternative if it could solve my problem.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Personally, I think that connecting to his computer using some sort of remote desktop solution will serve your purpose the best.

All you need to do, is setup a remote connection between the two systems, connect to his desktop and configure his connection as if you were right there next to him.

Personally I find that the FREE version of [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) is excellent and works wonders around firewalls and deep NAT networks.

Good luck!

Comment: We used LogMeIn, which worked amazingly great !

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you!

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: @Terrabits probably because this doesn't answer the question. The main clear question is how to export VPN settings and David Skrabal (and demoncodemonkey) bring the correct answer. And as akseli is suggesting some remote desktop solution to import those settings remotely, one need to export it first. Anyway LogMeIn is no more free software.

Answer (score 45):

On Windows7 the VPN settings are stored here:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```

So I copied the .pbk file to my other computer and opened it on there, and I managed to successfully connect to the VPN.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the accepted answer. The workaround using logmein may work for that one person but this answer works for everyone else. When you move the pbk files over they won't refresh until you do a full profile logoff/logon or reboot. Other than that works great!

Answer (score 19):

Current user:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```

or shared with all users:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```

Comment: This is the most correct and most helpful answer. This QA is a wreck. Thanks David.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do export the VPN settings AND password. The password is the problem since it is encrypted, and uses your key to decrypt it.

If you want to use your VPN as the end all method, you could both use TeamViewer (the quick support version does not even need to be installed, it just runs), and you could get access to his computer, and set up the VPN and password.

Comment: Depends what is the password. If it is the user password, every user shall have own account and remember own password. If it is about the connection PSK it is possible to bring it with a profile. Back in 2011 I've created by standard tools the EXE/CAB installer and while exploring the files, I can see even plaintext PSK. I can't remember how I created this EXE file, probably with the wizard within NPS. Nowadays Microsoft offers Microsoft Intune or System Center Configuration Manager to create profiles.

Answer (score 1):

simply use dialupass.exe : http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dialupass.html

- for pbk file:
  options > advanced options > Use the following phonebook (.pbk) file > browse

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. `dialupass` displays the passwords. OP wants to avoid that ("I don't want to share my password")